# how to save colour changes in table using php

Tags: php, html

how can I save the colour into database ? here is my coding.. I can change the table colour, but it doesn't save into database. While I'm open it again, the colour will turn to normal..

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<html>
<title>Test</title>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function colourRow1(rowNumber) {
    //some code to change the colour of the row indicated by the number
    alert("change row 1 background colour");

    var tr = document.getElementById('table1')
                 .getElementsByTagName('tr')[rowNumber-1];
    tr.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';


}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table name="table1" id="table1" border="1">
<thead>
<th>heading1</th>
<th>heading2</th>
<th>heading3</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr id="row1">
<td>1,1</td>
<td>1,2</td>
<td>1,3</td>
</tr>
<tr id="row2">
<td>2,1</td>
<td>2,2</td>
<td>2,3</td>
</tr>
<tr id="row3">
<td>3,1</td>
<td>3,2</td>
<td>3,3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button type="button"  onClick="colourRow1(1)" action="colourupdate.php">Change Row 1</button>
</body>
</html>
```

how can I save the colour into database ? here is my coding.. I can change the table colour, but it doesn't save into database. While I'm open it again, the colour will turn to normal..

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain another table for storing the color history..
Table structure like this

```
id | rowno | color
```

you need to store row number and color for each button click using a ajax call.

**Other Method is** 
Store row id and color as a Session for a particular period of time ..

```
$_SEESION['rowid']=$value;
$_SEESION['rowid']=$color;
```

Comment: tq sir, but can you properly show to me? the exactly way to save it into database? so in the next when open it, it still remain the same colour and other user also can see it. sorry, im still  new in programming